# Bands Names QGIS when merging rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I have downloaded landsat satellite data, then I merged the 4 bands I am interested in into one file (raster-merge). The problem is that I merged bands 2,3,4 and 8, and in the merged file the bands are named 1 to 4. The question is which band in the merged file corresponds to which individual raster band file.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using Landsat 8 product

from my experience, it should be:

band 2  → 1; 
band 3 → 2;
band 4 → 3;
band 8 → 4

you can do band combination like RGB (3,2,1) combination and if it show natural color then its true.
[image]
 4 is for band 8 which is panchromatic band

if you are still confuse, you can match the band min_max pixel values between before and after merge
[image]

Comment: thanks, but still not sure how to make sure which band corresponds to which

Comment: ypu can compare before and after merge and see the min_max pixel values for each band. you can see the updated answer.